# How I can configure Sonarqube to not require test coverage for cosmetic changes?

Tags: java, sonarqube

- SonarQube 7.7 (build 23042)
- SonarJava 5.13.1 (build 18282)
- Git 1.9 (build 1725)

Analysis: https://sonarqube.itextsupport.com/dashboard?branch=tech-debt-5-artem&id=com.itextpdf%3Aroot

Steps to reproduce:

- Clone https://github.com/itext/itext7
- Apply patch:
  (summary: mostly changes in whitespace and comments)
  (redacted to fit in character limit)

```
From 5e92cd1bd5cfe73e1a29fcf45081c59b5e19deed Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Artem Bobko <artem.bobko@duallab.com>
Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2019 20:15:42 +0300
Subject: [PATCH] Fix inline comments in barcodes, forms and io

---
 .../com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodeEANSUPP.java |   3 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodePostnet.java |  15 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/barcodes/qrcode/QRCode.java  |   3 +-
 .../itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.java   |   9 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/AnnotObject.java  |   4 +-
 .../forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectFactory.java         |   8 +-
 .../itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectUtils.java  |   3 +-
 .../forms/FormFieldFlatteningTest.java        |   9 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/forms/PdfFormFieldTest.java  |   6 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/io/font/FontEncoding.java    |   3 +-
 .../io/font/FontProgramDescriptorFactory.java |   6 +-
 .../itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramFactory.java  |   6 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GlyphLine.java   |   3 +-
 .../itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType4.java |   3 +-
 .../itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType5.java |   3 +-
 .../itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType6.java |   3 +-
 .../itextpdf/io/font/otf/GsubLookupType4.java |   3 +-
 .../itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFeature.java |   3 +-
 .../io/font/otf/OpenTypeFontTableReader.java  |   4 +-
 .../io/font/otf/OpenTypeGdefTableReader.java  |   9 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/io/image/BmpImageHelper.java |   3 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/io/image/PngImageHelper.java |  13 +-
 .../source/ByteBufferRandomAccessSource.java  |   3 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteUtils.java     |   6 +-
 .../com/itextpdf/io/source/PdfTokenizer.java  |   3 +-
 31 files changed, 342 insertions(+), 185 deletions(-)

diff --git a/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodeEANSUPP.java b/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodeEANSUPP.java
index 56df187db1..e5d1a465b4 100644
--- a/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodeEANSUPP.java
+++ b/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodeEANSUPP.java
@@ -70,7 +70,8 @@ public class BarcodeEANSUPP extends Barcode1D {
      */
     public BarcodeEANSUPP(Barcode1D ean, Barcode1D supp) {
         super(ean.document);
-        n = 8; // horizontal distance between the two barcodes
+        // horizontal distance between the two barcodes
+        n = 8;
         this.ean = ean;
         this.supp = supp;
     }
diff --git a/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodePostnet.java b/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodePostnet.java
index 63c49dfc8c..2c0c3697ba 100644
--- a/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodePostnet.java
+++ b/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/BarcodePostnet.java
@@ -75,11 +75,16 @@ public class BarcodePostnet extends Barcode1D {

     public BarcodePostnet(PdfDocument document) {
         super(document);
-        n = 72f / 22f; // distance between bars
-        x = 0.02f * 72f; // bar width
-        barHeight = 0.125f * 72f; // height of the tall bars
-        size = 0.05f * 72f; // height of the short bars
-        codeType = TYPE_POSTNET; // type of code
+        // distance between bars
+        n = 72f / 22f;
+        // bar width
+        x = 0.02f * 72f;
+        // height of the tall bars
+        barHeight = 0.125f * 72f;
+        // height of the short bars
+        size = 0.05f * 72f;
+        // type of code
+        codeType = TYPE_POSTNET;
     }

     /** Creates the bars for Postnet.
diff --git a/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/qrcode/QRCode.java b/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/qrcode/QRCode.java
index 64a91a00b5..2126a809d1 100644
--- a/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/qrcode/QRCode.java
+++ b/barcodes/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/barcodes/qrcode/QRCode.java
@@ -190,8 +190,9 @@ final class QRCode {
                         // ByteMatrix stuff.
                         matrix != null &&
                         matrixWidth == matrix.getWidth() &&
+                        // Must be square.
                         // See 7.3.1 of JISX0510:2004 (p.5).
-                        matrix.getWidth() == matrix.getHeight(); // Must be square.
+                        matrix.getWidth() == matrix.getHeight();
     }

     /**
diff --git a/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.java b/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.java
index fb1fcc75d5..2b6dc59a5f 100644
--- a/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.java
+++ b/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.java
@@ -2336,9 +2336,11 @@ public class PdfFormField extends PdfObjectWrapper<PdfDictionary> {
     }

     private String getRadioButtonValue(String value) {
-        assert value != null; //Otherwise something wrong with getValueAsString().
+        //Otherwise something wrong with getValueAsString().
+        assert value != null;
         if ("".equals(value)) {
-            value = "Yes"; //let it as default value
+            //let it as default value
+            value = "Yes";
             for (String state: getAppearanceStates()) {
                 if (!"Off".equals(state)) {
                     value = state;
@@ -3521,7 +3523,8 @@ public class PdfFormField extends PdfObjectWrapper<PdfDictionary> {
                 }
             }
         }
-        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // last '\n'
+        // last '\n'
+        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
         return sb.toString();
     }

diff --git a/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/AnnotObject.java b/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/AnnotObject.java
index c3f58a0dc2..b82458e4a1 100644
--- a/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/AnnotObject.java
+++ b/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/AnnotObject.java
@@ -77,7 +77,7 @@ public class AnnotObject {
      * Content model: text string.
      * For more details see paragraph 6.5.4 in Xfdf document specification.
      */
-    private PdfString contents;//basically text string
+    private PdfString contents;

     /**
      * Represents contents-richtext tag in Xfdf document structure. Is a child of caret, circle, fileattachment, freetext,
@@ -116,7 +116,7 @@ public class AnnotObject {
      * Content model: Base64 encoded string.
      * For more details see paragraph 6.5.1 in Xfdf document specification.
      */
-    private String appearance;//should be Base64String
+    private String appearance;

     /**
      * Represents the defaultappearance element, a child of the caret and freetext elements.
diff --git a/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectFactory.java b/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectFactory.java
index 6fd2755d15..5e32a63990 100644
--- a/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectFactory.java
+++ b/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectFactory.java
@@ -284,18 +284,20 @@ public class XfdfObjectFactory {
         for (int temp = 0; temp < children.getLength(); temp++) {
             Node node = children.item(temp);
             if (node.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
-                annotObject.setContents(new PdfString(node.getNodeValue()));//getTextContent?
+                // getTextContent?
+                annotObject.setContents(new PdfString(node.getNodeValue()));
             }
         }
     }

     private void visitContentsRichTextSubelement(Node parentNode, AnnotObject annotObject) {
-        //no attributes, inside a text string or rich text string
+        // no attributes, inside a text string or rich text string
         NodeList children = parentNode.getChildNodes();
         for (int temp = 0; temp < children.getLength(); temp++) {
             Node node = children.item(temp);
             if (node.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
-                annotObject.setContentsRichText(new PdfString(node.getNodeValue()));//getTextContent?
+                // getTextContent?
+                annotObject.setContentsRichText(new PdfString(node.getNodeValue()));
             }
         }
     }
diff --git a/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectUtils.java b/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectUtils.java
index 2414a41448..948181e2d4 100644
--- a/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectUtils.java
+++ b/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/xfdf/XfdfObjectUtils.java
@@ -164,7 +164,8 @@ final class XfdfObjectUtils {

         for(String flag : flagsList) {
             if (flagMap.containsKey(flag)) {
-                result += (int) flagMap.get(flag);//implicit cast  for autoporting
+                //implicit cast  for autoporting
+                result += (int) flagMap.get(flag);
             }
         }
         return result;
diff --git a/forms/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/forms/FormFieldFlatteningTest.java b/forms/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/forms/FormFieldFlatteningTest.java
index 63b11be770..e038315ea3 100644
--- a/forms/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/forms/FormFieldFlatteningTest.java
+++ b/forms/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/forms/FormFieldFlatteningTest.java
@@ -219,11 +219,14 @@ public class FormFieldFlatteningTest extends ExtendedITextTest {

                 Integer justification = field.getJustification();
                 if (null == justification || 0 == (int) justification) {
-                    field.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(255, 200, 200)); // reddish
+                    // reddish
+                    field.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(255, 200, 200));
                 } else if (1 == (int) justification) {
-                    field.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(200, 255, 200)); // greenish
+                    // greenish
+                    field.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(200, 255, 200));
                 } else if (2 == (int) justification) {
-                    field.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(200, 200, 255)); // blueish
+                    // blueish
+                    field.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(200, 200, 255));
                 }

                 field.setValue(newValue);
diff --git a/forms/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/forms/PdfFormFieldTest.java b/forms/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/forms/PdfFormFieldTest.java
index 2e0021fdcb..a92a278f32 100644
--- a/forms/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/forms/PdfFormFieldTest.java
+++ b/forms/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/forms/PdfFormFieldTest.java
@@ -178,7 +178,8 @@ public class PdfFormFieldTest extends ExtendedITextTest {
         PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filename));
         PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
         Map<String, PdfFormField> formFields = form.getFormFields();
-        String fieldName = "\u5E10\u53F71"; // 帐号1: account number 1
+        // 帐号1: account number 1
+        String fieldName = "\u5E10\u53F71";
         Assert.assertEquals(fieldName, formFields.keySet().toArray(new String[1])[0]);
     }

@@ -187,7 +188,8 @@ public class PdfFormFieldTest extends ExtendedITextTest {
         String filename = sourceFolder + "unicodeFormFieldFile.pdf";
         PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filename));
         PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
-        String fieldName = "\u5E10\u53F71"; // 帐号1: account number 1
+        // 帐号1: account number 1
+        String fieldName = "\u5E10\u53F71";
         Assert.assertNotNull(form.getField(fieldName));
     }
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontEncoding.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontEncoding.java
index 556bd5f59b..769aff2b30 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontEncoding.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontEncoding.java
@@ -290,7 +290,8 @@ public class FontEncoding implements Serializable {
     }

     protected void fillNamedEncoding() {
-        PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(" ", baseEncoding); // check if the encoding exists
+        // check if the encoding exists
+        PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(" ", baseEncoding);
         boolean stdEncoding = PdfEncodings.WINANSI.equals(baseEncoding) || PdfEncodings.MACROMAN.equals(baseEncoding);
         if (!stdEncoding && differences == null) {
             differences = new String[256];
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramDescriptorFactory.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramDescriptorFactory.java
index 1e15c15851..6b6988fa78 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramDescriptorFactory.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramDescriptorFactory.java
@@ -141,8 +141,10 @@ public final class FontProgramDescriptorFactory {
             String ttcName;
             int ttcIndex;
             try {
-                ttcName = baseName.substring(0, ttcSplit + 4); // count(.ttc) = 4
-                ttcIndex = Integer.parseInt(baseName.substring(ttcSplit + 5)); // count(.ttc,) = 5)
+                // count(.ttc) = 4
+                ttcName = baseName.substring(0, ttcSplit + 4);
+                // count(.ttc,) = 5)
+                ttcIndex = Integer.parseInt(baseName.substring(ttcSplit + 5));
             } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                 throw new IOException(nfe.getMessage(), nfe);
             }
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramFactory.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramFactory.java
index 6d8ee80796..501fb7489f 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramFactory.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramFactory.java
@@ -231,8 +231,10 @@ public final class FontProgramFactory {
                 int ttcSplit = baseName.toLowerCase().indexOf(".ttc,");
                 if (ttcSplit > 0) {
                     try {
-                        String ttcName = baseName.substring(0, ttcSplit + 4); // count(.ttc) = 4
-                        int ttcIndex = Integer.parseInt(baseName.substring(ttcSplit + 5)); // count(.ttc,) = 5)
+                        // count(.ttc) = 4
+                        String ttcName = baseName.substring(0, ttcSplit + 4);
+                        // count(.ttc,) = 5)
+                        int ttcIndex = Integer.parseInt(baseName.substring(ttcSplit + 5));
                         fontBuilt = new TrueTypeFont(ttcName, ttcIndex);
                     } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                         throw new IOException(nfe.getMessage(), nfe);
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GlyphLine.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GlyphLine.java
index 23a3f0de6f..08a7176e34 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GlyphLine.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GlyphLine.java
@@ -293,7 +293,8 @@ public class GlyphLine implements Serializable {
     }

     public void substituteOneToMany(OpenTypeFontTableReader tableReader, int[] substGlyphIds) {
-        int substCode = substGlyphIds[0]; //sequence length shall be at least 1
+        //sequence length shall be at least 1
+        int substCode = substGlyphIds[0];
         Glyph glyph = tableReader.getGlyph(substCode);
         glyphs.set(idx, glyph);

diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType4.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType4.java
index 37102c865c..917a90f448 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType4.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType4.java
@@ -124,7 +124,8 @@ public class GposLookupType4 extends OpenTableLookup {
     protected void readSubTable(int subTableLocation) throws java.io.IOException {
         openReader.rf.seek(subTableLocation);

-        openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort(); //skip format, always 1
+        // skip format, always 1
+        openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort();
         int markCoverageLocation = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort() + subTableLocation;
         int baseCoverageLocation = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort() + subTableLocation;
         int classCount = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort();
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType5.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType5.java
index aec6d2eae4..298982e196 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType5.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType5.java
@@ -126,7 +126,8 @@ public class GposLookupType5 extends OpenTableLookup {
     protected void readSubTable(int subTableLocation) throws java.io.IOException {
         openReader.rf.seek(subTableLocation);

-        openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort(); //skip format, always 1
+        // skip format, always 1
+        openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort();
         int markCoverageLocation = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort() + subTableLocation;
         int ligatureCoverageLocation = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort() + subTableLocation;
         int classCount = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort();
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType6.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType6.java
index 1e210082ad..af9c53fe55 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType6.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GposLookupType6.java
@@ -128,7 +128,8 @@ public class GposLookupType6 extends OpenTableLookup {
     protected void readSubTable(int subTableLocation) throws java.io.IOException {
         openReader.rf.seek(subTableLocation);

-        openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort(); //skip format, always 1
+        // skip format, always 1
+        openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort();
         int markCoverageLocation = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort() + subTableLocation;
         int baseCoverageLocation = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort() + subTableLocation;
         int classCount = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort();
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GsubLookupType4.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GsubLookupType4.java
index 2acf98c3b7..b543081aed 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GsubLookupType4.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/GsubLookupType4.java
@@ -104,7 +104,8 @@ public class GsubLookupType4 extends OpenTableLookup {
     @Override
     protected void readSubTable(int subTableLocation) throws java.io.IOException {
         openReader.rf.seek(subTableLocation);
-        openReader.rf.readShort(); //subformat - always 1
+        // subformat - always 1
+        openReader.rf.readShort();
         int coverage = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort() + subTableLocation;
         int ligSetCount = openReader.rf.readUnsignedShort();
         int[] ligatureSet = new int[ligSetCount];
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFeature.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFeature.java
index d88e4f8180..fa7edb936d 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFeature.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFeature.java
@@ -58,7 +58,8 @@ public class OpenTypeFeature implements Serializable {
         openTypeReader.rf.seek(locationFeatureTable);
         TagAndLocation[] tagsLocs = openTypeReader.readTagAndLocations(locationFeatureTable);
         for (TagAndLocation tagLoc : tagsLocs) {
-            openTypeReader.rf.seek(tagLoc.location + 2); //+2 don't use FeatureParams
+            // +2 don't use FeatureParams
+            openTypeReader.rf.seek(tagLoc.location + 2L);
             int lookupCount = openTypeReader.rf.readUnsignedShort();
             FeatureRecord rec = new FeatureRecord();
             rec.tag = tagLoc.tag;
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFontTableReader.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFontTableReader.java
index d0f889778f..e59d5c98f1 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFontTableReader.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeFontTableReader.java
@@ -233,7 +233,9 @@ public abstract class OpenTypeFontTableReader implements Serializable {
     final void startReadingTable() throws FontReadingException {
         try {
             rf.seek(tableLocation);
-            /*int version =*/ rf.readInt(); //version not used
+            /*int version =*/
+            // version not used
+            rf.readInt();
             int scriptListOffset = rf.readUnsignedShort();
             int featureListOffset = rf.readUnsignedShort();
             int lookupListOffset = rf.readUnsignedShort();
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeGdefTableReader.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeGdefTableReader.java
index 02a301cfac..e3f82eed9f 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeGdefTableReader.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/font/otf/OpenTypeGdefTableReader.java
@@ -67,10 +67,13 @@ public class OpenTypeGdefTableReader implements Serializable{
     public void readTable() throws java.io.IOException {
         if (tableLocation > 0) {
             rf.seek(tableLocation);
-            rf.readUnsignedInt(); //version, we only support 0x00010000
+            // version, we only support 0x00010000
+            rf.readUnsignedInt();
             int glyphClassDefOffset = rf.readUnsignedShort();
-            rf.readUnsignedShort(); //skip Attachment Point List Table
-            rf.readUnsignedShort(); //skip Ligature Caret List Table
+            // skip Attachment Point List Table
+            rf.readUnsignedShort();
+            // skip Ligature Caret List Table
+            rf.readUnsignedShort();
             int markAttachClassDefOffset = rf.readUnsignedShort();
             if (glyphClassDefOffset > 0) {
                 glyphClass = OtfClass.create(rf, glyphClassDefOffset + tableLocation);
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/BmpImageHelper.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/BmpImageHelper.java
index 273e0f6916..52d68e9676 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/BmpImageHelper.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/BmpImageHelper.java
@@ -552,7 +552,8 @@ final class BmpImageHelper {
     }

     private static boolean getImage(BmpParameters bmp) throws java.io.IOException {
-        byte bdata[]; // buffer for byte data
+        // buffer for byte data
+        byte[] bdata;
         // if (sampleModel.getDataType() == DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE)
         //     bdata = (byte[])((DataBufferByte)tile.getDataBuffer()).getData();
         // else if (sampleModel.getDataType() == DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT)
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/PngImageHelper.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/PngImageHelper.java
index 730e43d9b9..cbdfb012ac 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/PngImageHelper.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/PngImageHelper.java
@@ -91,7 +91,8 @@ class PngImageHelper {
         int transGreen = -1;
         int transBlue = -1;
         int inputBands;
-        int bytesPerPixel; // number of bytes per input pixel
+        // number of bytes per input pixel
+        int bytesPerPixel;
         byte[] colorTable;
         float gamma = 1f;
         boolean hasCHRM = false;
@@ -329,7 +330,7 @@ class PngImageHelper {
                     float XC = YC * png.xB / png.yB;
                     float ZC = YC * ((1 - png.xB) / png.yB - 1);
                     float XW = XA + XB + XC;
-                    float YW = 1;//YA+YB+YC;
+                    float YW = 1;
                     float ZW = ZA + ZB + ZC;
                     float[] wpa = new float[3];
                     wpa[0] = XW;
@@ -679,10 +680,12 @@ class PngImageHelper {
                 dstX = xOffset;
                 for (srcX = 0; srcX < width; srcX++) {
                     int idx = outPixel[srcX];
-                    if (idx < png.trans.length)
+                    if (idx < png.trans.length) {
                         v[0] = png.trans[idx];
-                    else
-                        v[0] = 255; // Patrick Valsecchi
+                    } else {
+                        // Patrick Valsecchi
+                        v[0] = 255;
+                    }
                     setPixel(png.smask, v, 0, 1, dstX, y, 8, yStride);
                     dstX += step;
                 }
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteBufferRandomAccessSource.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteBufferRandomAccessSource.java
index 7873b6a5bb..66be3002cd 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteBufferRandomAccessSource.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteBufferRandomAccessSource.java
@@ -102,7 +102,8 @@ class ByteBufferRandomAccessSource implements IRandomAccessSource, Serializable
             byte b = byteBuffer.get((int) position);
             return b & 0xff;
         } catch (BufferUnderflowException e) {
-            return -1; // EOF
+            // EOF
+            return -1;
         }
     }

diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteUtils.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteUtils.java
index c67a0978bb..d899b267bc 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteUtils.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/ByteUtils.java
@@ -212,7 +212,8 @@ public final class ByteUtils {
             }
             int fracLen = 0;
             if (v % 100 != 0) {
-                fracLen = 2;                             //fracLen include '.'
+                //fracLen include '.'
+                fracLen = 2;
                 if (v % 10 != 0) {
                     fracLen++;
                 } else {
@@ -222,7 +223,8 @@ public final class ByteUtils {
                 v /= 100;
             }
             buf = buffer != null ? buffer : new ByteBuffer(intLen + fracLen + (negative ? 1 : 0));
-            for (int i = 0; i < fracLen - 1; i++) {     //-1 because fracLen include '.'
+            //-1 because fracLen include '.'
+            for (int i = 0; i < fracLen - 1; i++) {
                 buf.prepend(bytes[v % 10]);
                 v /= 10;
             }
diff --git a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/PdfTokenizer.java b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/PdfTokenizer.java
index 598cf9c68e..83bafc71fd 100644
--- a/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/PdfTokenizer.java
+++ b/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/source/PdfTokenizer.java
@@ -257,7 +257,8 @@ public class PdfTokenizer implements Closeable, Serializable {
             String str = readString(arrLength);
             int idx = str.lastIndexOf("startxref");
             if (idx >= 0) return pos + idx;
-            pos = pos - arrLength + 9;                  // 9 = "startxref".length()
+            // 9 = "startxref".length()
+            pos = pos - arrLength + 9;
         }
         throw new IOException(IOException.PdfStartxrefNotFound, this);
     }
-- 
2.20.1
```

- Run a SonarQube analysis

Actual result:

- whitespace changes are detected as new lines to cover
- comment changes are detected as new lines to cover
- 119 lines detected as new code to cover
- code coverage on new code is too low
- Quality Gate fails

Expected result:

- Only 2 lines (in `OpenTypeFeature.java` and `BmpImageHelper.java`) have new lines to cover.
- Both lines are covered by tests, so there should be 100% coverage on new code.
- For calculation of coverage on new code, SonarQube ignores changes to whitespace
- For calculation of coverage on new code, SonarQube ignores changes to comments
- Quality Gate passes

**Question**

How do I make sure that SonarQube does not see changes in whitespace&comments as "new code" that needs to be covered by tests? Writing tests that cover the code is not in scope for the current task.

Comment: @Michael thank you for the edit, I approve.

Comment: I'm not sure though about removing the `git` tag, because to calculate which code is "new", SonarQube uses Git (something like `git diff -w`, probably). Or more precisely, it uses **JGit**, the Java implementation of Git. This technical detail is crucial, because JGit doesn't behave exactly the same as command line Git, as I have unfortunately learned (I have some other SO questions&answers on that topic).

Comment: I found this tantalizing SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527215/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-comments however it is about command line **Git**, and SonarQube uses **JGit**.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/metric-definitions/) regarding the definitions SonarQube uses.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I read it and it does not answer my question. The definitions are ambiguous. I'm going to be opinionated about it and make it very clear. *Whitespace is not code* (In Java), and is trivial to filter out with `git diff -w` (or it's JGit equivalent). *Comments are not code*, and can be filtered out with `git diff -G<regex>` - slightly more convoluted, but doable. If _I_ can do that with **command line `git`**, then surely SonarQube can do it with **JGit**?

Comment: I don't think what you want it is possible. Maybe you have more luck when using the [community](https://community.sonarsource.com/) forum.

Comment: I asked on the community forum before I asked here...

Comment: I still haven't found a solution. We now have to disable quality gates every time a developer edits a comment.