# Trying to get git diff to ignore comments using regex, doesn't seem to be working

Tags: regex, git, diff

My goal is to get git diff to ignore C comments. I've been using a basic regex, and printing the diff to another file (it doesn't print anything otherwise). I've also tried the reverse, to get the diff to only show the *comments* (I'll later see if I can reverse engineer it). However, it doesn't behave as it's supposed to. Here's a few examples of what I've tried:

Trying to get the diff to show only the lines that begin with /*:

```
git diff -w -G'(^(/\**)' master > text.diff
```

Getting the diff to show lines that start with either * *or* / or end with the same:

```
git diff -w -G'(^[/\*])|($[^/\*])' master > text.diff
```

Getting the diff to show only non-comment lines (see [How to make 'git diff' ignore comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527215/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-comments/35301258)):

```
git diff -w -G'(^[^\*# /])|(^#\w)|(^\s+[^\*#/])' master > text.diff
```

I'm running it under WSL and using git version 2.17.1 for reference.

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to get git diff to ignore C comments ...

This is difficult, because:

- Git doesn't understand C code;
- parsing C comments requires lexical analysis across multiple lines;
- `git diff` breaks up the input into lines too early.

Your best bet is therefore *not* to do this directly with `git diff` at all.  Instead:

1. Extract the file(s) to be compared from wherever they live (two commits, one commit and a regular file, one commit and an index copy of a file, etc).
2. Use a C-comment-stripper that *does* understand how to analyze C source and detect (and remove<sup>1</sup>) the comments.
3. Run the output of step 2 through some diff engine (regular diff, `git diff`, whatever you like).

If you wrap all of this up as a tool that `git difftool` can run, you'll get something serviceable and convenient.  It will require generating lots of temporary files.

(Note that your attempt to use `-G` here is ultimately doomed.  The `-G` expression will look for a comment *within the changed lines*, rather than whether the changed line is or is not in the middle of a long comment.  Languages that have only comment-to-end-of-line, such as sh/bash, are more tractable than C.  Backslash-newline sequences will still foil things though.  See also [Erik Aronesty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65223867/1256452) to the linked question.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that in ANSI C, comments always separate tokens, so for ANSI C, replace comments with white-space, but in many traditional K&R compilers, comments simply vanish.  This technique is used in place of the new-in-1989 token-pasting operator in some very old C code.  You might want to support this mode by making step 2 have an option to leave out the white-space.

Comment: You can set up a textconv to automatically run the filter on the text before diff (or, notably, blame) looks at it, no need to wrangle the filtering manually.

Comment: @jthill: true—but that wrecks the diffs where you *do* want to see the comment differences. I wouldn't want that myself. Making it a diff tool seems wiser. I can put that note in the answer itself if you like, though.

Comment: mmm, yes, you could use a scratch no-checkout clone to set up a local .git/config and .git/info/attributes, `git clone -ns . ../scratch; git ls-files -oc | cpio -pdl ../scratch; cp .git/index ../scratch/.git/index; cd ../scratch`, that'd run real quick and you could use templates for the clone with the various differs preconfigured. kludgy but fast, I'm probably too fond of solutions like that.

Comment: Clever indeed. I'm not sure whether I'm impressed or appalled. :-) Seriously, sometimes having the implementation-guts exposed is a good thing, but sometimes it's not, and things like this are good inputs for these arguments.

Comment: Wait, am I in "forms some sort of argument in that debate" territory? I am soooo proud :-)