# Compare files ignoring numeric differences

Tags: git, git-diff

I work with a codebase that has a lot of duplication. It seems the files were copied and then slightly modified, say bumping version numbers in string output and creation time-stamps.

Is there a way to tell `git diff` to ignore lines (a) in which only a specific number or digit is replaced by another (e.g. `version_5` and `version_6`) or (b) in which the difference is digits only?

I know that `git diff` is quite flexible and I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527215/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-comments) about ignoring comments, but I don't see how I find out anything about the difference between two lines (like, if it's only digits that are different).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to tell `git diff` to ignore numeric changes.

You could pre-filter the files with `sed` and then pass them to the regular `diff` command. For example, here we use `sed` to convert all numbers to `_`, and compare the current version of the file to the version in the parent commit:

```
diff -u \
  <(git show HEAD:path/to/file | sed 's/[0-9]/_/g') \
  <(git show HEAD^:path/to/file | sed 's/[0-9]/_/g')
```