# How can I calculate the number of lines changed since last commit in Git?

Tags: git, statistics

Is there an easy way to calculate number of lines changed in tracked files since last commit? This is about monitoring changes that are not commited yet. Context is that I would like to write a tool that will warn me when I modify large portion of code and haven't commited these changes (facilitate atomic commits). I know I can do `git status` or `git status --short` and extract modified (and not tracked) files. Then I can use `git diff --stat <file>` and loop over files to extract number of changed lines.
Is there any one- or few-liner solution that could do that in bash/zsh or python?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18810623/96588) answer your  question?

Comment: @l0b0 - actually yes. One of the answers offer to display diff with zero lines of context and display lines that starts with `+` or `-`. SO the best solution for me  would be:
`git diff -U0 | grep '^[+-]' | grep -Ev '^(--- a/|\+\+\+ b/)' | wc -l`. Thank you for pointing me to the other question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff --stat | tail --lines=1` (or `-n1` in BSD land) should give you what you want, if I understand correctly:

> 6 files changed, 726 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to calculate the LOC difference then you can run this command to get the LOCs (reference SO Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822516/970422)

```
git ls-files | xargs cat | wc -l
```

You can run this command on the parent branch and in your local copy to get the difference in LOCs.

Comment: This counts the number of **ALL** lines in the git repository, not only changed.

Comment: My 2nd part after the command mentions this. Run this 2 times and calculate the difference. Run it on your local copy AND run it on the parent branch. Then just get the difference between the two

Comment: Please show the two commands. How to run `git ls-files` on the parent branch? [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) shows information about **files in the index and the working tree**, not on a branch.