# How to get the output of git diff command in Shell Script

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to perform Git diff in two branches with the same file. I want to get the difference of two files.

- If there is a fatal error
- If there is a difference/ not matched
- If there is NO difference/ matched

I tried saving the command in a variable to get the result. Example: GIT_DIFF=$(git diff RB_202005:/test.txt RB_202006:/test.txt) and then printing the variable (Example: echo $GIT_DIFF) but nothing is being returned.

Comment: Maybe try capturing `stderr` also,

Comment: Hello. Can you give an example of the usage of stderr? Thank you very much.

Comment: here `2>&1` use that and see if it solve your issue.

Comment: Is this correct?
GIT_DIFF=$(git diff RB_202005:/test.txt RB_202006:/test.txt 2>&1)

Another question, how should I print the stderr?

Comment: `echo "$GIT_DIFF"` and see.

Comment: Hello. Nothing was printed out after echo "$GIT_DIFF".

Comment: If those two files match, `git diff` prints nothing, so the variable is set to the empty string and printing it prints nothing. Only if the two files differ, or there is some error in computing the diff, will the variable be set to something other than the empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the cases "no diff", "diff", "error", I would run a

```
git diff --exit-code --quiet .....
```

`--exit-code` sets the exit code in the way the normal `diff` would do.

`--quiet` suppresses the output.

If the exit code is 0, you don't have differences.

If the exit code is 1, you have differences.

If the exit code is 2 or 128, you have fatal errors.

**UPDATED** As the OP pointed out in the comment, `git-diff --exit-code` produces status code 128, if the file to be compared does not exist. According to the man-page, it should produce the same exit code as the standard `diff`, which would be 2. Hence it is best to treat any exit code larger than 1 as standard error. This would also catch the case that `git` itself is not found (in which case the shell would likely report exit code  127).

Comment: Yes, but be careful and save it to a different variable immediately after running `git diff, because every command afterwards (including, say, any `echo`) will overwrite `$?`.

Comment: In my case, Exit Code 128 is when there are fatal errors. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Roan: Indeed, I could reproduce it. To me it seems to be a bug, because it contradicts the description given in the man-page.  I suggest that you catch any exit code larger than 1 as fatal error, in case the git developers fix this one day.

Comment: Just `git diff --quiet` works, because it [implies --exit-code](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---quiet).

Comment: @Roan : Exit code 128 really looks like a bug. A process is not supposed to set this explicitly. "Normal" exit codes are below 126 - see [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Answer (score 0):

This would not always work with the new (Git 2.30, Q1 2021) [`git diff -I`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758633/6309), should you want to ignore a diff pattern.

"[`git diff -I<pattern> -exit-code`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/296d4a94e7231a1d57356889f51bff57a1a3c5a1/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L684-L688)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>" should exit with 0 status when all the changes match the ignored pattern, but it didn't.

See [commit 50f0439](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50f04394908fe308a421b360951b1f73b00363ee) (16 Dec 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 59fcf74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59fcf746f5a6253b3c0a84a94ecd5cf1add56e3a), 18 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50f04394908fe308a421b360951b1f73b00363ee): correct interaction between `--exit-code` and `-I<pattern>`

> Just like "[`git diff -w --exit-code`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/50f04394908fe308a421b360951b1f73b00363ee/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L675)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-))</sup> should exit with 0 when ignoring whitespace differences results in no changes shown, if ignoring certain changes with "[`git diff -I<pattern> --exit-code`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/296d4a94e7231a1d57356889f51bff57a1a3c5a1/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L684-L688)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>" result in an empty patch, we should exit with 0.
>
> The test suite did not cover the interaction between "`--exit-code`" and "`-w`"; add one while adding a new test for "`--exit-code`" + "`-I`".