# Way to have git only recognize a file as changed if more than a specific set of lines change?

Tags: git, rhapsody

In my current project, I am attempting to use git to version control text files that are utilized by software that generates code from them. This in itself isn't a problem, the problem is that every time I generate code, it automatically updates this file with properties such as the date the code was generated, as well as my name.

You can imagine it looking something like this:

```
SomeHeader{
  -SomeProperty : x
  -NameOfUserThatGenerateCode: myName
  -DateTimeCodeGenerated: 2013-07-23 06:28
  -SomeOtherProperty: y
}
```

What I want, is a way to tell git to say that "it is okay" if both the Name and CodeGeneration time to change (ie: Ignore that there was a change), but DO care if "SomeProperty" changes to say "z".

In that second case, it would commit the entire file (with the updated autogenerated files).

Is there anyway to do that? I recognize that git does changes at the "file" level, but I am hoping that there might be some sort of pre-processing hook that I can tie into that would only work when git attempts to compare file changes.

For those that care, this will enable me to properly version control rhapsody files.

Comment: someone already asked that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382447/can-git-ignore-specific-lines-matching-a-pattern

Comment: I had saw that stackoverflow article... it doesn't quite do what I want as I can't get rid of the "special" properties. I am going to be trying VonC's response to see if that might work.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend:

- keeping a copy of those files (as private files, meaning not versioned): your software would generate code in those copy
- a `clean` script, as a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5132569/6309), declared in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) (detailed in [Git Pro book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)).

[image: http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0703-tn.png]

The idea is for that script to **detect, on `git add`**:

- the content of a 'SomeHeader' property file
- if the *copy* of that file has changed in way you need to keep (in which case you overwrite the versioned file with the content of that copy)
- if the *copy* of that file has not changed significantly, in which case, you don't modify the actual property file.

Note that the "keep a copy" part can be automated also by a content filter driver, with a `smudge` script activated automatically on `git checkout`.

Comment: Thinking it through, while I think this approach may work, it seems like it is going to be a headache to implement as Rhapsody has many many files in different directories.
What I think I am going to do instead is find a way of "deleting" the varying parts via a filter so that only the unchanged pieces are in the repository.